# How to add a vertical line representing the value for a specific observation in ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a histogram displaying the area distribution of 12,000 observations with area on the x-axis and frequency of a given area on the y-axis.

I want to add a vertical line which sits at the area of a specific observation on the x-axis.
I have been trying various combinations of the geom_vline function without success

```
ggplot(a_b, aes(x=a_area_km)) +
  geom_histogram(fill= 'light blue', bins = 20) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept= a_b$identifier == '1540')) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

Any help would be appreciated

| ID | AREA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.8493732 |
| 2 | 1.9130095 |
| 3 | 2.3303074 |
| 4 | 0.8634214 |
| 5 | 0.5458977 |
| 6 | 1.5271307 |
| 7 | 12.4303822 |
| 8 | 0.6196505 |
| 9 | 2.0999631 |
| 10 | 0.2086267 |
| 11 | 0.6889139 |
| 12 | 1.0927132 |
| 13 | 10.9666451 |
| 14 | 4.6828732 |
| 15 | 0.2302338 |

Comment: Hi I have updated now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a vertical line at the value of the 1540 row of `a_area_km` then you should do `xintercept= a_area_km[1540]`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(a_b, aes(x=a_area_km)) +
  geom_histogram(fill= 'light blue', bins = 20) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept= a_area_km[1540])) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
a_b <- data.frame(a_area_km = rgamma(12000, 3, .5))

a_b$a_area_km[1540]
[1] 5.573579
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
ggplot(a_b, aes(x=a_area_km)) +
   geom_histogram(fill= 'light blue', bins = 20) +
   geom_vline(aes(xintercept= a_area_km[match(1540, identifier)])) +    
   scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10")
```